# How would you write Yuna in a Chinese poetic name?

Tags: translation, names

I'm trying to come up with a Chinese name for myself that has a poetic meaning and still sounds like my English name. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for information, I have a grandniece called 匀娜, (Yún Na), (Uniformly Graceful)

Answer (score 1):

Chinese characters with /yun/ pinyin that suitable for female names: 雲(cloud), 苑(garden), 韻 (melody)

Chinese characters with /na/ pinyin that suit for female names: 娜 (graceful), 南(south)

Suggestions:

雲娜 /Yúnnà/ (graceful cloud)

韻娜 /Yùn nà/ (graceful melody)

苑南 /Yuàn nán/ (gardern in the south)

韻南 /Yùn nán/ (melody of the south)

~

Chinese characters with /yu/ pinyin that suitable for female names: 玉 (jade), 羽 (feather), 魚 (fish), 毓 (educate; raise)

Suggestions:

毓南 /Yǔ nán/ (raised in the South)

毓娜 /yù nà/ (educated, graceful lady)

> **毓娜** /yù nà/ fit 'Yuna' the most in pinyin

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I'd like to use the characters 昀 or 羽 so in your opinion would 昀娜／羽娜 be a suitable name for me?

Comment: @Yuna 昀娜 /Yún nà/ (Lady of graceful sunlight ) is more meaningful, 羽娜  /Yǔ nà/ (Lady of the graceful feather) fit pinyin better. Personally, I like 昀娜 better, but 羽 is a common character and 昀 is a rare character (few people use it or even know it)

Answer (score 0):

尤娜（[Yuna](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B0%A4%E5%A8%9C/33786?fr=aladdin)） Heroine of a computer game! Have a look, see if she looks like you!

，是日本游戏制作商史克威尔艾尼克斯出品的电子游戏最终幻想系列第十部《Final Fantasy Ⅹ》（最终幻想Ⅹ）中的虚拟角色，女主角。

Heroine of a computer game!

But apparently, there is a man's name Yona also translated as 尤娜

Comment: I remember Yuna from Final Fantasy! We do share similar facial features but we're still very different.